# Get updated int value

Tags: c#, value-type, reference-type

**1st code snippet:**

```
object a = 10;
object b = a;
Console.WriteLine("b :"+ b);
a = 20;
Console.WriteLine("after a updateb :" + b);
```

I have this code snippet its answer is 10 and 10 (IMO! it should be 10 and 20 because i am using reference type not value type like **int**). I want that if a variable become change then its assigned var should be updated. I know that it is not possible using this:

**2nd code snippet**

```
int a = 10;
int b = a;
Console.WriteLine("b :" + b);
a = 20;
Console.WriteLine("after a updateb :" + b);
```

Because the above code will only copy the value. But whats wrong with the first code snippet? How can i do this

Comment: You are using a reference type.  What do you think `object` is?

Comment: yes object is reference type!

Comment: Use `b.GetType()` and see that what you are acutally doing is changing the value of an Int!

Comment: Long story short -  boxing doesn't magically converts value types to reference types.

Answer (score 9):

Both snippets return 10. Both are correct.

In the first case both `a` and `b` hold a reference to a boxed instance of 10. That boxed instance isn't lost when you store a different reference to `a`.

In the second case, `b` holds a copy of `a`'s value.

If you wanted `b` to hold a reference to `a` you should have used `ref int` to declare that the variable holds a reference. This is a new feature in C# 7 :

```
int a = 10;
ref int b = ref a;
Console.WriteLine("b :" + b);
a = 20;
Console.WriteLine("after a updateb :" + b);
```

Returns

```
b :10
after a updateb :20
```

Comment: This is the only answer that answers the question.

Comment: to do this pre c# you can declare a class to hold the value https://dotnetfiddle.net/FXNxzj

Answer (score 4):

In the first snippet, `a` is of type object. Therefore the assignment

```
a = 20;
```

is treated by the compiler as if this was written:

```
a = (object)20;
```

That assigment means that a new object is created on the heap, and the pointer `a` is then updated to point to this new object. Meanwhile the pointer `b` is still pointing to the original object (which still contains `10`) on the heap.

Comment: This is good info, but doesn't answer the question of how to get b set to 20 as a reference to a.

Comment: @JacobH exactly

Answer (score 1):

### For Snippet 1:

It is because when primitive type is stored as `Object`, the boxing would happen and a new memory would be used for it :

```
object a = 10; // 10 is boxed and reference holded in variable a
object b = a;  // variable b also refers to the same reference which variable a is referring
Console.WriteLine("b :"+ b);
a = 20; // variable a now points to a new memory location with value 20
```

So when memory reference of `a` got updated to point to `20`, the `b` is still pointing to the old memory location which `a` was referring before the line `a=20;`

So `b` is pointing to the location where `10` was residing to which originally `a` was referring but the `a` now refers to a new location.

### For Snippet 2:

You have both value types so every one has it's own copy there so changing `a` would not change `b` in this case.

Hope it clears the confusion.